# How can I get current file path using boost?

Tags: c++, boost

How can I get the current file path using boost? Like in a.cpp, I can get

/home/src/a.cpp

I can use `＿FILE＿` macro to get this, but I can't use `＿FILE＿`due to some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may be a little confused. What is a "current file", really? The file open in your IDE? Then you need to ask your IDE. Th file currently being compiled? Then you need to ask your compiler (Why can't you use \_FILE\_?). The file from which came the code currently being executed? Then you can't ask anyone because compiled code doesn't know what file it came from. Nowhere does Boost come in.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
    boost::filesystem::path full_path(boost::filesystem::current_path());
```

or

```
auto p = boost::filesystem::current_path()
```